# Cut and paste not working on Samsung Note 10.1?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I recently bought a Samsung Note 10.1 tablet. It has Android 4.0.4 (model number `GT-N8000 / N8000XXLGA`). All is fine, but I cannot understand why the cut and paste do not work. Is this a known problem? Can I update to a newer version or something...? Every application in which I try to copy/cut & paste from just crashes.

This is extremely annoying and I've been trying to find a solution online for about a week now.

Any ideas...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An upgrade became available yesterday. Once I upgraded to 4.1.1, the cut and paste functionality started working again! :)